# Recycleview not populated with JSON and Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

I am making a simple app in which the user will able to search for books by its name, with google.com book api. For now, I wish to present a list of books with android in their name. I am doing it with Retrofit2 and RecycleView, but nothing is showing.
 MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
KnjigaAdapter knjigaAdapter;
List<KnjigaModel> listaKnjiga;
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    uzmiKomentare();
}

public void uzmiKomentare() {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
   KnjigaApi knjigaApi = retrofit.create(KnjigaApi.class);
     final Call<KnjigaModel> pozivZaListuKnjiga = knjigaApi.getKnjige("android");

    pozivZaListuKnjiga.enqueue(new Callback<KnjigaModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<KnjigaModel> call, Response<KnjigaModel> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                return;
            }
       //generateRecycleView(WHAT TO PUT HERE!!!!);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<KnjigaModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("MainActivity:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
private void generateRecycleView(List<KnjigaModel> knjige) {
    listaKnjiga = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
    knjigaAdapter = new KnjigaAdapter(this, knjige);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(knjigaAdapter);
    if (knjigaAdapter.getItemCount() == 0){
        Log.i("List is empty: ","YES");
    }
    else {
        Log.i("list is empty: ","No");
    }
}
```

}

api inteface:

```
public interface KnjigaApi {
@GET("v1/volumes")
Call<KnjigaModel> getKnjige(@Query("q") String knjiga);
```

}

model class:

```
public class KnjigaModel {
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String imeKnjige;
@SerializedName("authors")
@Expose
private String imeAutora;
@SerializedName("thumbnail")
@Expose
private String slikaKnjige;

public KnjigaModel(String imeKnjige, String imeAutora,String slikaKnjige) {
    this.imeKnjige = imeKnjige;
    this.imeAutora = imeAutora;
    this.slikaKnjige = slikaKnjige;
}

public String getImeKnjige() {
    return imeKnjige;
}

public String getImeAutora() {
    return imeAutora;
}

public String getSlikaKnjige() {
    return slikaKnjige;
}
```

}

and my adapter:

```
public class KnjigaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KnjigaAdapter.KomentariViewHolder> {
private List<KnjigaModel> listaKnjiga;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public KnjigaAdapter(Context context, List<KnjigaModel> listaKnjiga) {
    this.listaKnjiga = listaKnjiga;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public KomentariViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

     inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    // Inflate the custom layout
    View postView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
    // Return a new holder instance
    return new KomentariViewHolder(postView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(KomentariViewHolder holder, int position) {
    KnjigaModel knjige = listaKnjiga.get(position);
    holder.naslovKnjige.setText(knjige.getImeKnjige());
    holder.imeAutora.setText(knjige.getImeAutora());
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(knjige.getSlikaKnjige())
            .into(holder.slikaKnjige);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaKnjiga.size();
}


public class KomentariViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView naslovKnjige;
    private TextView imeAutora;
    private ImageView slikaKnjige;


    public KomentariViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        naslovKnjige = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ime_knjige);
        imeAutora = itemView.findViewById(R.id.autor_knjige);
        slikaKnjige = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sika_korica);
    }
}
```

}

my JSON format:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I strongly recommend to use RxJava for asynchronous requests, though it's totally optional.

Your Problem:
Your "getKnjige" Method returns only ONE Model, though the endpoint is named volumes (plural), you need to wrap your KnjigaModel in a class like 
`data class KnjigaResponse(val items: List<KnjigaModel>)`
(Kotlin for simplicity, you can also generate a Java class with a single member volumes member that holds a list of KnjigaModel)

In addition, your model is wrong. *authors* is not a string, but a List of Strings, and "*thumbnail*" is wrapped in an "*imageLinks*" Object, and *title* is wrapped in a *volumeInfo* Object.


Your retrofit interface then would look like this:

```
public interface KnjigaApi {
@GET("v1/volumes")
Call<KnjigaResponse> getKnjige(@Query("q") String knjiga);
```

Request:

```
     final Call<KnjigaResponse> pozivZaListuKnjiga = knjigaApi.getKnjige("android");

    pozivZaListuKnjiga.enqueue(new Callback<KnjigaResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<KnjigaResponse> call, Response<KnjigaResponse> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                return;
            }
         generateRecycleView(response.items);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<KnjigaResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("MainActivity:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```